# How to declare modal component outside of AppModule?

Tags: modal-dialog, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to use `modal navigation` in my `{N} app` but I'm getting lots of errors. One of those is the following one:

```
Error: No component factory found for RootModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

Which obviously tells me to declare the `RootModalComponent` inside the `entryComponents` of the `appModule`. Which I did.

But according to `Nativescript` demo app (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-ui-category/modal-view-ng), for the Modal navigation to work correctly, the `RootModalComponent` should be declared inside the module where the `component` triggering the `RootModalComponent` is declared.

```
@NgModule({
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routerConfig)
],
declarations: [
    RootModalComponent,
    HomeModalViewContentComponent,
    SecondModalViewContentComponent,
],
entryComponents: [RootModalComponent]
})

export class ModalViewExamplesModule {
    constructor() { }
}
```

When doing this, I get the error mentioned above. Did I miss something?

Comment: I think that's an open issue with Angular itself, you can't use `entryComponents` outside module unless it's specified in AppModule.

Comment: Well in this demo he is doing it https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-ui-category/modal-view-ng

Comment: I was referring to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324), if you are using your `RootModalComponent` within the same module it's declared it should not be an issue. I recall you had been facing this issue with lazy loaded tabs, did you try replacing router outlets in each tab with simple tab view item.

Comment: @Manoj thanks a lot for your help, I replaced the router outlets with simple tabs, which now works, but navigation breaks after calling `this.modalParams.closeCallback()`, when trying to call `navigate([...], ...)`, it won't work... did you face the same issue?

Comment: @Manoj you can find here a more complete Playground that details all what I am doing https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=TkK7sQ&v=3 ! As you can see, you can `login`, `logout`, but when you close the modal, `navigation` is broken!